# Regularity for a semilinear problem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

we are facing the following problem:
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ open bounded. Consider the elliptic operator $L = -div(a\cdot \nabla u)$, where $a_{i,j}$, where $a_{i,j}\in C^2(\Omega)$ are symmetric and uniformly elliptic.

Assume that $u\in H^1$ is a weak solution to $Lu = f(u)$ in $\Omega$.

Assume further that $a_{i,j}\in C^3(\Omega)$ and that $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ with $||f‘‘||_{L^\infty}, ||f‘||_{L^\infty} < \infty$. Show that $u\in H^4_{loc}$, provided that the space dimension $d$ is not too large.

In the lecture we had the following (higher regularity) theorem:

Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $L$ as above, $f\in H^m, u\in H^1$ weak solution of $Lu = f$. Then $u\in H^{m+2}_{loc}$.

As a hint we got that we should use sobolev embeddings.

Unfortunately, we have no clue what to do. May someone help please?

Comment: The trick is to consider $f(u)$ as a given right-hand side: first show $f(u)\in L^2$, which implies $u\in H^2_{loc}$. Then improve the regularity of $f(u)$ to $H^1$, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this helped to find a point to start.